# How can I add a curve to a scatter plot if ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm conducting an audit of paracetamol overdoses.  I'm creating a scatter plot of blood levels vs time post ingestion.  This is pretty simple: however, treatment is governed by whether their blood level is above or below the line `y=1986*0.840897^t` where `t` is time and `y` = the blood level for the values `t=4:16`.

How can I superimpose a function like that on top of a scatter plot with `ggplot2`?

Essentially I want  to create something a bit like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Define your own function, pass it to `stat_function()` and you're all set.

```
set.seed(357)

# simulate some data, rnorm() is used to add some noise
x <- seq(from = 4, to = 6, length.out = 10)
y <- 1986*0.840897^x + rnorm(10, sd = 30)
xy <- data.frame(x, y)

# define function
myfun <- function(x) 1986*0.840897^x

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(xy, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point() +
  stat_function(fun = myfun)
```

[image]